# Most popular category listed with every row redshift database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I require the following data:
e.g.
sweden male brandA EUR
sweden female brandA EUR
sweden male brandB EUR
england male brandA EUR
england female brandA EUR
england male brandB EUR
england female brandC EUR

EUR came from the fact that of 8000 people, 5000 use euro, 2000 use gbp and 1000 use SEk . SO the most popular currency is EURO. I would like it displayed for every line

to get the most popular currency, max_curr

and for every row returned to have a column called max_curr with this value displayed

```
    select 
cdl.country
,cd.gender
,cd.brand
,t.max_curr
from customer_data_list cdl  
left join customer_data cd on cd.customerid = cdr.customerid
left join 
(
    select 
        trans.customerid, a.*
    from
    (
        select
            a.*
            ,max(count_currency) over() as max_curr
        FROM
        (
            select 
                t.currency
                ,count(t.currency) as count_currency
            from transactions t
            where t.function = 'DEPOSIT' and t.status = 'ACCEPTED' 
            group by t.currency
            order by currency
        ) a
    ) a
    left join transactions trans on trans.currency = a.currency 
    where count_currency = max_curr) t on t.customerid = cdl.customerid
```

This is not returning what I require because most max_curr column entries are empty.
Can someone help please?

Comment: It is hard to assess what you expect from just your explanation and query. Please share sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desire results, and explain what YOU mean by "most popular currency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for each customer, you want the currency that is used most often for ACCEPTED, DEPOSIT transactions, then you can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select cc.*
from (select t.customerid, t.currency, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.customerid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t
      where t.function = 'DEPOSIT' and
            t.status = 'ACCEPTED' 
      group by t.customerid, t.currency
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

For the revised interpretation of the question, just use a cross join:

```
select t.customerid, t.currency, count(*) as cnt,
       tt.currency as most_popular_currency
from transactions t cross join
     (select t.currency
      from transactions t
      where t.function = 'DEPOSIT' and
            t.status = 'ACCEPTED'
      group by t.currency
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) tt
where t.function = 'DEPOSIT' and
      t.status = 'ACCEPTED' 
group by t.customerid, t.currency
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like the overall most popular currency to be displayed for all customers . So in other words, the column would be the same for all. If EUR is the most popular overall, then the column max_curr would be EUR for all customers